# security error:script execution is disabled on this system:I can’t access Sharepoint from Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell-script

I am in the process of configuring my Sharepoint Framework development environment, I installed node.js and visual code everything is fine but after the powershell level I ran into this error that I can’t fix? please help me!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not the issue with the SPFx framework command, it is the issue with local Windows PowerShell execution policy which can be fixed by the below command:

Before running the yo command - run the below PowerShell Command:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

Other PowerShell execution policy are as below:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
or 
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope "CurrentUser" -ExecutionPolicy "Unrestricted"
or
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope "CurrentUser" -ExecutionPolicy "RemoteSigned"
```

For more details refer to the below article:

[PowerShell cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system windows 10](https://www.sharepointsky.com/powershell-cannot-be-loaded-because-the-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled/)

Apparently, if you execute the above the **yo** command in the **node.js** command prompt, you will not face this issue.

For setting up the development environment for SharePoint Framework (SPFx), you may refer to the below article:

[SharePoint Framework (SPFx) development environment Setup step by step](https://global-sharepoint.com/sharepoint-online/sharepoint-framework-spfx-development-environment-setup-step-by-step/)

Comment: yes it worked well thank you very much

Comment: Glad to know it worked and helped you. Could you please mark this as answered - so that it will help the upcoming visitors. Thanks for your understanding :-)

Comment: okay it's clear with pleasure

Comment: Ohh I think you are new to this site :-) what I meant is - in the left side panel of my answer, there is a up and down arrow - here the rule is, if someone's answer is helpful people will click on the up vote by clicking on up arrow and the original asker can click on  the grey toggle button as accept the answer, then the answer will be marked as green ticked icon. :-) Here is details explanation how to mark the answer as accepted :  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Welcome@chirazazzabi  to SE, Please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted in case, it helped you and solved your issue!

Comment: @Chiraz Azzabi - Could you please mark this as answered, incase this has helped you - so that it will help to the upcoming visitors. Thanks for your understanding :-)